# Bootstrap Datepicker and DataTables fnDraw() issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have a Bootstrap datepicker range, which I call the setDate function as shown:

```
$('.input-daterange').datepicker({
                        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                        todayBtn: "linked",
                        calendarWeeks: true,
                        autoclose: true,
                        todayHighlight: true
                    });

$('#fromDate, #toDate').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

with the corresponding html being:

```
<table>
     <tr class="input-daterange input-group" id="datepicker">
       <td>
          <input id="fromDate" type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start"/>
          <span id="toDate" class="input-group-addon">to</span>
          <input type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" /> 
       </td>                     
     </tr>
</table>
```

Now, I am also using DataTables which is using the `fnDraw()` method to redraw my tables data based on certain UI changes, one of them being listening to `.change` of my date ranges.

When I try and set the default date (of today) using the above JS code, then I get the following error:

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'fnDraw' of undefined
>   or null reference

How can I prevent this from happening, or how can I set the default date, without using the setDate method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what backend you're using but could you set the default dates server side by setting the input's value like so: E.g for rails you could use

```
<input value="<%= Date.today.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %>" id="fromDate" type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="start"/>
<span id="toDate" class="input-group-addon">to</span>
<input value="<%= Date.tomorrow.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') %>" type="text" class="input-sm form-control" name="end" />
```

I am using this method to set the default date for bootstrap-datepicker in an app of mine.

I guess you would also have to give your datatable default dates to work with too so it would show the correct data to begin with.

Comment: I'm using .net, and yes I can do this. However, i'd like to understand why it's causing the issue.